# overflow hidden with border-radius and translate3d

Tags: html, css

When content of block with `overflow: hidden;` and `border-radius` translated, its corners aren't hidding. Is there any solution to fix this?
HTML

```
<div class="scroller">
    <div class="scroller-content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scroller{
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scroller-content{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aZ5Qn/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webkit border radius combined with css3 translate3D bleeding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470796/webkit-border-radius-combined-with-css3-translate3d-bleeding)

Comment: @EvanMulawski it doesn't help, try it yourself, its hides after border.

Comment: this is a bug in webkit:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25499

Answer (score 5):

Accually, you can just put

`transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`

On your element that needs the `overflow` + `border-radius` combo...

Answer (score 3):

Since you are not using the z in the translate, you can change it to translate2d, that does work:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/aZ5Qn/3/)

```
.scroller{
width: 300px;
height: 500px;
border: 3px solid red;
border-radius: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.scroller-content{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: green;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -8px);
}
```

This is documented in the link that Chtiwi Malek provided, but there it states that is only for mobile browser, and I have this issue in desktop.

**edit**

It also works (at least in desktop) if you set overflow and transform in *the same element*

```
.scroller{
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;   
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 5px);
}
.scroller-content{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I need translate3d

Comment: Like vals mentions, just set a small translate3d on the container to make overflow:hidden work. I used transform: translate3d(0, 0, -1px);